# for any positive integer $n$, there exists a prime whose digit sum is greater than $n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Hint: Use Dirichlet's Theorem.

Since $(10^{n},10^{n}-1) = 1$, there exists an integer $m$ such that $p = 10^{n}m + 10^{n} - 1$ is prime. How do I guarantee that the digit sum of $p$ is greater than $n$?

Comment: As $p=????\ldots ?\underbrace{999\ldots 9}_n$, you have digit sum at least $9n$.

Comment: Why do you use $m$ as a variable rather than $k = m + 1$.  If $k = m + 1$ then $10^nm +10^n - 1 = 10^n(m+1) - 1 = 10^nk - 1$. We wouldn't we use that.  It's simpler.  ANd as Hagen von Eitzen points out the last $n$ digits of that are $9$......

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing variables up; let $p=10^km+10^k-1$. Then given $n$, set $k\ge\frac n9$ so that $p$ ends in $k$ nines and has a digit sum of at least $9k\ge n$.